# How to match two sets of points?How to find those points that have similar positions (close enough) in python?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, closest-points

I have two sets of extracted points (each element of points set include (x,y) coordinates) in two different image (d:database image, q:query image), each set may have a different number of points `(d={(xj,yj)}, where j=1:n) and (q={(xi,yi)}, where i=1:m)`. I have to check those points that they are spatially consistent between two sets. Your help is appreciated. 
This is the representation of two point sets:

This is d, and red point in the center is object center:

[image]

and this is q:

[image]

How to find (the indices of matched points in two sets) those points that they have similar positions relative to the center of `d`? How to match these two sets of points and find those that they are spatially consistent (similar position) relative to the center?

Comment: So you just want to check if they have similar radii?

Comment: @chrisz I do not have center of `q`, so the points in q should be close enough to the points in `d`, in which we have distance from the center. that means the location of two matched points should be sufficiently close and their difference should be less than a threshold. Thanks

Comment: Then maybe `abs(pi.x - qi.x) < epsilon and abs(pi.y - qi.y) < epsilon`?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. How to set this epsilon to be optimum, as a good start for testing?

Comment: Start larger than you think is necessary, then go smaller until you are satisfied with results.

Comment: @rayryeng Thank you very much for your comment, previously, what I did was manually transformed points in `d` with 8 rotations and 8 scaling factor. This is the first time, I am hearing about ICP, is there python package? Thanks a lot once again

Comment: @S.EB This one is one I've used quite often: https://github.com/ClayFlannigan/icp.  However, the duplicate link I showed you above has a custom implementation written out using OpenCV and Python.

Comment: @rayryeng thanks for sharing the link, could I ask, as I see in `icp.py` the number of points in A and B should be same? but the number of points in two sets of my problem are not same? In that case, will it work?

Comment: @S.EB Ah, OK. You're right.  This will not work.  I missed that you didn't have matching points.  There is a variant called Coherent Point Drift algorithm that does not assume this: https://github.com/siavashk/pycpd

Comment: @rayryeng thanks for your help. I tried to run the [sample code](https://github.com/siavashk/pycpd/blob/master/examples/fishAffine2D.py) , this is a kind of registering two points set and finding the transformation. The output of `reg.register(callback)` is an array with which shows the transformation not the matching points. Or maybe I do not know how to use it. I edited my question, could you please guide me whether `CPD` is applicable to my problem? I want to find the indices of those points that are matching together in two sets.